# Detect Brute Force Attack in auth.log

Tags: linux, security, logs, forensics

I´m very new to linux forensics and I´m analyzing an infected linux image.

Main question:
**How got the hacker access to the system?**

The auth.log file is full with automated brute force attack with failed passwords. But at the end it seems for me that the access didn´t worked via the brute force attack. The attacker simply added the user php with a sudo command (Check line 2280).

Am I right with my realization that the brute force attack didn´t worked and the root user created the php user. So the attacker got somehow root access?

P.S. Also I would be very happy if someone could explain me the structure of the line 2280. Couldn´t find something which explains the basic structure of auth.logs to me in detail.

```
2240  Oct  5 12:52:21 VulnOSv2 sshd[2346]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2241  Oct  5 12:52:21 VulnOSv2 sshd[2346]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2242  Oct  5 12:52:21 VulnOSv2 sshd[2349]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57654 ssh2
  2243  Oct  5 12:52:21 VulnOSv2 sshd[2349]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2244  Oct  5 12:52:21 VulnOSv2 sshd[2349]: PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2245  Oct  5 12:52:22 VulnOSv2 sshd[2351]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2246  Oct  5 12:52:24 VulnOSv2 sshd[2351]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57656 ssh2
  2247  Oct  5 12:52:24 VulnOSv2 sshd[2351]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2248  Oct  5 12:52:24 VulnOSv2 sshd[2353]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2249  Oct  5 12:52:24 VulnOSv2 sshd[2355]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2250  Oct  5 12:52:26 VulnOSv2 sshd[2353]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57658 ssh2
  2251  Oct  5 12:52:26 VulnOSv2 sshd[2353]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2252  Oct  5 12:52:26 VulnOSv2 sshd[2355]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57660 ssh2
  2253  Oct  5 12:52:26 VulnOSv2 sshd[2355]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2254  Oct  5 12:52:28 VulnOSv2 sshd[2357]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2255  Oct  5 12:52:28 VulnOSv2 sshd[2358]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2256  Oct  5 12:52:30 VulnOSv2 sshd[2358]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57664 ssh2
  2257  Oct  5 12:52:30 VulnOSv2 sshd[2357]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57662 ssh2
  2258  Oct  5 12:52:30 VulnOSv2 sshd[2358]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2259  Oct  5 12:52:30 VulnOSv2 sshd[2357]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2260  Oct  5 12:52:32 VulnOSv2 sshd[2362]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2261  Oct  5 12:52:32 VulnOSv2 sshd[2361]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2262  Oct  5 12:52:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[2362]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57668 ssh2
  2263  Oct  5 12:52:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[2361]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57666 ssh2
  2264  Oct  5 12:52:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[2362]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2265  Oct  5 12:52:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[2361]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2266  Oct  5 12:52:35 VulnOSv2 sshd[2365]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2267  Oct  5 12:52:36 VulnOSv2 sshd[2367]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2268  Oct  5 12:52:38 VulnOSv2 sshd[2365]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57670 ssh2
  2269  Oct  5 12:52:38 VulnOSv2 sshd[2367]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57672 ssh2
  2270  Oct  5 12:52:38 VulnOSv2 sshd[2365]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2271  Oct  5 12:52:38 VulnOSv2 sshd[2367]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2272  Oct  5 12:52:50 VulnOSv2 sshd[2372]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2273  Oct  5 12:52:50 VulnOSv2 sshd[2370]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=root
  2274  Oct  5 12:52:52 VulnOSv2 sshd[2372]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57676 ssh2
  2275  Oct  5 12:52:52 VulnOSv2 sshd[2370]: Failed password for root from 192.168.210.131 port 57674 ssh2
  2276  Oct  5 12:52:52 VulnOSv2 sshd[2370]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2277  Oct  5 12:52:52 VulnOSv2 sshd[2372]: Connection closed by 192.168.210.131 [preauth]
  2278  Oct  5 13:00:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2438]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
  2279  Oct  5 13:00:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2438]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
  2280  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/tmp ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/useradd -d /usr/php -m --system --shell /bin/bash --skel /etc/skel -G sudo php
  2281  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
  2282  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 useradd[2525]: new group: name=php, GID=999
  2283  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 useradd[2525]: new user: name=php, UID=999, GID=999, home=/usr/php, shell=/bin/bash
  2284  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 useradd[2525]: add 'php' to group 'sudo'
  2285  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 useradd[2525]: add 'php' to shadow group 'sudo'
  2286  Oct  5 13:06:38 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2287  Oct  5 13:08:31 VulnOSv2 chsh[2536]: changed user 'mail' shell to '/bin/bash'
  2288  Oct  5 13:09:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2543]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
  2289  Oct  5 13:09:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2543]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
  2290  Oct  5 13:09:03 VulnOSv2 chpasswd[2558]: pam_smbpass(chpasswd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user mail.
  2291  Oct  5 13:09:03 VulnOSv2 chpasswd[2558]: pam_unix(chpasswd:chauthtok): password changed for mail
  2292  Oct  5 13:09:03 VulnOSv2 chpasswd[2558]: pam_smbpass(chpasswd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user mail.
  2293  Oct  5 13:09:18 VulnOSv2 usermod[2561]: add 'mail' to group 'sudo'
  2294  Oct  5 13:09:18 VulnOSv2 usermod[2561]: add 'mail' to shadow group 'sudo'
  2295  Oct  5 13:13:53 VulnOSv2 sshd[2624]: Accepted password for mail from 192.168.210.131 port 57686 ssh2
  2296  Oct  5 13:13:53 VulnOSv2 sshd[2624]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mail by (uid=0)
  2297  Oct  5 13:14:04 VulnOSv2 sudo:     mail : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/mail ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
  2298  Oct  5 13:14:04 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2299  Oct  5 13:14:04 VulnOSv2 su[2721]: Successful su for root by root
  2300  Oct  5 13:14:04 VulnOSv2 su[2721]: + /dev/pts/1 root:root
  2301  Oct  5 13:14:04 VulnOSv2 su[2721]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2302  Oct  5 13:17:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2789]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
  2303  Oct  5 13:17:01 VulnOSv2 CRON[2789]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
  2304  Oct  5 13:18:23 VulnOSv2 su[2721]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
  2305  Oct  5 13:18:23 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2306  Oct  5 13:18:48 VulnOSv2 sshd[2713]: Received disconnect from 192.168.210.131: 11: disconnected by user
  2307  Oct  5 13:18:48 VulnOSv2 sshd[2624]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mail
  2308  Oct  5 13:18:54 VulnOSv2 sshd[2825]: Accepted password for mail from 192.168.210.131 port 57704 ssh2
  2309  Oct  5 13:18:54 VulnOSv2 sshd[2825]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mail by (uid=0)
  2310  Oct  5 13:19:21 VulnOSv2 sudo:     mail : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/mail ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
  2311  Oct  5 13:19:21 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2312  Oct  5 13:19:21 VulnOSv2 su[2884]: Successful su for root by root
  2313  Oct  5 13:19:21 VulnOSv2 su[2884]: + /dev/pts/1 root:root
  2314  Oct  5 13:19:21 VulnOSv2 su[2884]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2315  Oct  5 13:19:40 VulnOSv2 su[2884]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
  2316  Oct  5 13:19:40 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2317  Oct  5 13:19:42 VulnOSv2 sshd[2873]: Received disconnect from 192.168.210.131: 11: disconnected by user
  2318  Oct  5 13:19:42 VulnOSv2 sshd[2825]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mail
  2319  Oct  5 13:20:57 VulnOSv2 sshd[2999]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.210.131  user=mail
  2320  Oct  5 13:20:59 VulnOSv2 sshd[2999]: Failed password for mail from 192.168.210.131 port 57706 ssh2
  2321  Oct  5 13:21:03 VulnOSv2 sshd[2999]: Accepted password for mail from 192.168.210.131 port 57706 ssh2
  2322  Oct  5 13:21:03 VulnOSv2 sshd[2999]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mail by (uid=0)
  2323  Oct  5 13:21:11 VulnOSv2 sudo:     mail : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/mail ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
  2324  Oct  5 13:21:11 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2325  Oct  5 13:21:11 VulnOSv2 su[3055]: Successful su for root by root
  2326  Oct  5 13:21:11 VulnOSv2 su[3055]: + /dev/pts/1 root:root
  2327  Oct  5 13:21:11 VulnOSv2 su[3055]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2328  Oct  5 13:21:19 VulnOSv2 su[3055]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
  2329  Oct  5 13:21:19 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2330  Oct  5 13:21:24 VulnOSv2 passwd[3080]: passwd: can't view or modify password information for php
  2331  Oct  5 13:21:30 VulnOSv2 sudo:     mail : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/mail ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
  2332  Oct  5 13:21:30 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2333  Oct  5 13:21:30 VulnOSv2 su[3082]: Successful su for root by root
  2334  Oct  5 13:21:30 VulnOSv2 su[3082]: + /dev/pts/1 root:root
  2335  Oct  5 13:21:30 VulnOSv2 su[3082]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2336  Oct  5 13:21:34 VulnOSv2 passwd[3097]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user php.
  2337  Oct  5 13:21:39 VulnOSv2 passwd[3097]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for php
  2338  Oct  5 13:21:39 VulnOSv2 passwd[3097]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user php.
  2339  Oct  5 13:21:44 VulnOSv2 su[3082]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
  2340  Oct  5 13:21:44 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2341  Oct  5 13:21:45 VulnOSv2 sshd[3048]: Received disconnect from 192.168.210.131: 11: disconnected by user
  2342  Oct  5 13:21:45 VulnOSv2 sshd[2999]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mail
  2343  Oct  5 13:23:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[3108]: Accepted password for mail from 192.168.210.131 port 57708 ssh2
  2344  Oct  5 13:23:34 VulnOSv2 sshd[3108]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mail by (uid=0)
  2345  Oct  5 13:23:39 VulnOSv2 sudo:     mail : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/mail ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
  2346  Oct  5 13:23:39 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2347  Oct  5 13:23:39 VulnOSv2 su[3164]: Successful su for root by root
  2348  Oct  5 13:23:39 VulnOSv2 su[3164]: + /dev/pts/1 root:root
  2349  Oct  5 13:23:39 VulnOSv2 su[3164]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by mail(uid=0)
  2350  Oct  5 13:24:09 VulnOSv2 su[3164]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
  2351  Oct  5 13:24:09 VulnOSv2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  2352  Oct  5 13:24:11 VulnOSv2 sshd[3156]: Received disconnect from 192.168.210.131: 11: disconnected by user
  2353  Oct  5 13:24:11 VulnOSv2 sshd[3108]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mail
```

Comment: "Brute force attacks" are run by an automated attack tool. The tool reports "this system, these credentials worked" to the attacker. Later attacks use this information.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you very much for the fast reply. So I am not possible to see when the attacker got the right credentials? If yes then I should see at least a successful Login after the Last login fail from line 2275 or not?

Comment: There is no formal documentation for the log file, beyond the first few fields. Any program can log any message they think would be useful; `sudo` logs successful executions with details about each command if you configure it to.